# Lazy tips ? (Like Visual Studio)

Tags: zerobrane

I recently discover Löve and Zerobrane, I come from VB.NET on Visual Studio 2013/17 and I look for configure some tricks.

After some search, I write this in system preferences :

```
acandtip.fillups = " +-*/%.,(){}[]"
```

Whith it, auto complete is quick (generally, I accept suggestion and I use these keys to continue my line)

But I don't find preferences for this :
When I write "if true" and I press Enter, Visual Studio automaticaly write :

```
if true then
   --my cursor is here
end
```

(Same trick on function, for, etc ...)

Another trick that I don't find :
When I write "a=b+c", Visual Studio automaticaly write :

```
a = b + c
```

It's very usefull when you read your code ;)

I'm french, maybe I don't find correct words on google to find these preferences.

Thanks for your read and maybe for your help :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ZeroBrane Studio doesn't automatically add those whitespaces and doesn't add `then end` snippets when typing `if true` in the current version.